# Centering a specific table column to the page

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with two columns. I want to center the right-most column with the page so the left column would hang off to the left.

```
<table width="960" border="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
   <td width="100"><!--COLUMN TO HANG TO LEFT--></td>
 <td><!--COLUMN TO BE CENTER WITH PAGE--></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm assuming the solution will be CSS.

Comment: You don't need a table if your data (hopefully it's data!) has only two columns...

Comment: True, but I'm using the table for the main site layout. :)

Comment: I thought that using tables for layout is a technique which nowadays is used only to scare kids. ;-) You may consider reading [a few articles on alistapart.com](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlayouts/) for example.

Comment: There is no excuse for continuing to use a table for layout... especially something as simple as a two column layout.  **Joseph** correctly answered your question but the modern concept presented by **J-Bangin'**, using pure CSS, is really the proper way you should go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to wrap your table in a div, and center that:

```
<div style="width:1060px; margin: auto">
    <table width="960" border="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="100">COLUMN TO HANG TO LEFT</td>
            <td style="background: #ccc">COLUMN TO BE CENTER WITH PAGE</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9HgpM/embedded/result/

Answer (score 5):

You are right - CSS is the way to go.  Give the column an `id` or `class` that you can target and and in your CSS center it. Assuming your table width is where you want it, give it a width of your table subtracting the other column that is to the left.
Something like this:

HTML:

```
<table width="960" border="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
   <td width="100"><!--COLUMN TO HANG TO LEFT--></td>
   <td class="center"><!--COLUMN TO BE CENTER WITH PAGE--></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
   td.center { 
            text-align: center;
            width: 860px;   
           }
```

***Edit: Based on the comments below, here is a sample layout just using div's instead of a table***
http://jsfiddle.net/willyrybone/8eR6G/

HTML:

```
 <div id="page-wrap"> 
    <div id="sidebar"> 
        <p>this is some</p> 
        <p>sidebar content</p> 
    </div> 
    <div id="main-content"> 
        <p>This is some</p> 
        <p>centered main content</p> 
    </div> 
<div>
```

CSS:

```
#page-wrap {
                width: 960px;
                margin: auto;
            }

#sidebar  {
                float:left;
                width: 100px;
                background: #eee;
            }

#main-content {
                text-align:center;
                background:#bbb;
            }
```

Comment: I could have been implementing this incorrectly, but when I tried this it only centered the content within the second column.

Comment: that's what i read your original post to mean. " I want to center the right-most column with the page so the left column would hang off to the left." Maybe it's unclear about the final effect you are going for, but there are some links posted above that may help you.  if your data isn't several rows from an actual table you probably want to switch to <div> tags for the layout.  net.tutsplus.com and css-tricks.com are good resources as well when starting out.  They both have good video tutorials with source downloads so you can work along with the presenter.